# Trying to collect data from a document in one firestore db collection to display it in another collection document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a project that has a booking form where the submitted data from each user is stored in a Firestore Database within a collection named "bookings"; I have already successfully implemented Cloud Functions which adds a document to another collection named "mail" when data is submitted to the bookings collection. However, I have only been able to grab and display the ID of the newly created bookings collection document in the new document that is created in the mail collection; I would like the exact same data to be extracted from the submitted document in the bookings collection to then show in the new document in the mail collection.

In my src folder of my project, I have the form that users submit data into thus creating a document in the bookings collection in my firestore database. Here is the code for the relevant part:

```
function BookingForm({selectedDate,selectedTime,setFormVisible,bookingAddedForTheUser}) {
    const [isNewUser, setIsNewUser] = useState(false);
    const [parentNeeded, setIsParentNeeded] = useState(false);
    const [agreed, setAgreed] = useState(false);
    const [yearOfBirth, setYearOfBirth] = useState("2000");

    const bokingsCollection = collection(db,"bookings");

    const yearList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        yearList.push((1922+i)+"");
    }

    const ageUpdated = (e) => {
        const selectedYear = parseInt(e.target.innerHTML);
        setYearOfBirth(selectedYear+"");
        const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        
        setIsParentNeeded(currentYear - selectedYear < 18);
    }

    const saveBookingToFirebaseExisging = async (values,resetForm) =>{
        values.date = selectedDate;
        values.time = selectedTime;
        values.createdat = Timestamp.now();

        await addDoc(bokingsCollection,values).then((res)=>{
            bookingAddedForTheUser(selectedDate,selectedTime.dbTime);
        });

        setFormVisible(false);

        resetForm();
    }
```

In my root directory, I have my functions folder w all the necessary cloud function material. This folder is where I have my functions index.js file with the code that creates a new document in the mail collection when a new document is created in the bookings collection.
Here is the code for that:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require ("firebase-admin");

exports.mailTrigger = functions.firestore.document("/{collection}/{id}")
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
        console.log(snap.data());

        const collection = context.params.collection;
        const id = context.params.id;

        const mail = admin.firestore().collection("mail");

        if (collection === "bookings") {
            return mail.add(id.saveBookingToFirebaseExisging);
        }

        return null;
    })

admin.initializeApp();
```

I believe its the data from the const saveBookingToFirebaseExisging that I need, just not sure how to actually grab this data to then post in the new document in the mail collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting data from a newly created document in `bookings` collection and adding it to `mail` collection you have to get that newly created data first by using `snap.data()`.

You were trying to get data from `saveBookingToFirebaseExisging` function which exists on client side and you are trying to calling from server side which is not possible, to get the data you can use the following:

And you were initializing admin sdk after the function, I will recommend you to initialize at the top of the function like I have done it here

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
// Always initialize admin sdk instance at the top means before using it
admin.initializeApp();

exports.mailTrigger = functions.firestore.document("bookings/{id}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const bookingData = snap.data();
      console.log("New booking data:", bookingData);
      console.log("Id: ", context.params.id);
      // We can have the access of newly created booking Id too
      const mail = admin.firestore().collection("mail");

      const mailData = {
        // copy fields from the bookings document to the mail document
        name: bookingData.name,
        email: bookingData.email,
        date: bookingData.date,
        time: bookingData.time,
        createdAt: bookingData.createdAt,
        // You can also create timestamp for this field like below:
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // optional
      };
      await mail.add(mailData);
      return null;
    });
```

With this you can populate all the data from the newly created document in the `bookings` collection in `mail` collection.

References : [Trigger a function when a new document is created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created)